# Visual Studio Online - manage layered application sources

Tags: .net, version-control, azure-devops

We are developing a multi-layer pretty big web application, that has two solutions (backend and frontend) and each solution has plenty projects in it. With some of them being shared in both solutions.
Now the senior full-stack developer has access to all of it, and opens simply two Visual Studios and works on the whole application at once.
Wheras some junior front-end developers, should have access only to one project where we store the html stuff. And be able to work on it and commit.
What is the best approach and how can it be done with Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set it up so that some people have access to some of the code and not all of the code? If you are using TF VC (centralized version control), you can simply set the permissions for the folders as you need. If you are using Git, you can't set granular permissions per folder or item. You can set permissions for branches, but I don't know if that would help you - you would have to make sure never to merge the code that you don't want exposed to people who are supposed to see it. The best approach would likely be to have two repos. One for the full stack developers and one for the other devs. Then you can keep them completely separated.